# Is it possible to POST to the SQS url using the post body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html

```
https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/MyQueue/
?Action=SendMessage
&MessageBody=This+is+a+test+message
```

This works fine, however is it possible to send the payload using the post body?

I have an external service sending json payloads in the post body (at a very high throughput). It would be ideal if I can simply feed them the SQS url directly, and avoid having to create a AWS api gateway --> lambda --> SQS stack.

I'm open to alternative solutions.

Comment: I'm doing this with API Gateway + SQS (no Lambda) using a VTL body mapping template in API Gateway to transform the raw body JSON into what SQS expects... it's hackish-looking, but elegant at the same time.  That is as close as you can get, AFAIK, because `POST`s to SQS essentially require the same thing in the body as you have, now, in the query string, but dropped into the body.  Would that be of interest?

Comment: That would be awesome, can you post a mini tutorial of what you did to transform the json post body.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This may not have been *exactly* what the designers of API Gateway had in mind, but given...

- the way the AWS Query APIs (as used by the SDKs) work on the wire for services like SQS -- url-encoded key/value pairs in the standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, and
- the fact that the built-in body mapping template language in API Gateway (VTL) exposes `$util.urlEncode()`, and
- the fact that API Gateway can transparently sign requests when sending them to a backend service

...this means you can simply construct a valid API request -- a form post -- by hand, as were, using a VTL template, that encapsulates the original message body -- urlencoded, and that's all we need.  We don't actually care that it's JSON, as long as it is valid character data.

With this solution, a Lambda function is avoided, and the client does not need to know anything about how SQS expects messages to be formatted.

The entire incoming request body becomes the `Message` in SQS.

---

In the API Gateway console:

Create the resource (e.g. `/`) and the method (e.g. `POST`).

In the Integration Request settings:

```
Integration type: AWS Service
AWS Region: [select your region]
AWS Service: Simple Queue Service (SQS)
AWS Subdomain [leave blank]
HTTP Method: POST
Action Type: Use path override
Path override: /
Execution Role: [your role ARN, needs to be able to send a message to the queue]
Credentials cache: Do not add caller credentials to cache key
Content Handling: Passthrough
```

Under `HTTP Headers`, add one header, `Content-Type`.  This value should be specified as being "mapped from" `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` -- note that this is a single-quoted string.

Under `Body Mapping Templates`, choose `Never`.

Add a `Content-Type` of `application/json` and use the following mapping template:

```
Action=SendMessage##
&QueueUrl=$util.urlEncode('https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/000000000000/my-queue-name')##
&MessageBody=$util.urlEncode($input.body)##
```

And you have an API that transforms the a raw JSON input body into an SQS `SendMessage` API request.

The `##` at the end of each line are for readability -- VTL is a text templating language, so whitespace and newlines are preserved.  Placing `##` at the end of each line causes the newline to be stripped, which is necessary for building a correct web form.  Otherwise, the entire body mapping template would need to be on a single line.

Deploy and then test:

```
$ curl -X POST https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1 --data '{"works": true}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Response:

```
{"SendMessageResponse":{"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"bbbbbbbb-aaaa-5555-8888-334ed25bb6b3"},"SendMessageResult":{"MD5OfMessageAttributes":null,"MD5OfMessageBody":"81f2ecc3cb027268138bdfe7af0f8a3f","MessageId":"cccccccc-dddd-4444-1111-542e08bb39af","SequenceNumber":null}}}
```

For extra credit, a body mapping template in the Integration Response can be reused to customize the response, as well.

Comment: You're amazing, The missing piece of the puzzle I needed was `$util.urlEncode($input.body)` . I'm a try it first thing tomorrow!

Comment: Is it possible to add MessageAttribute as well using a body mapping template? I've asked a question here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877403/aws-api-gateway-connect-to-sqs-with-message-attributes

Comment: @JohnWebb yes, there is.  I've provided an answer to that question.

Comment: Can anyone help me to find the resource name of the API? Like I want that to be passed into the SQS and later retrieve from a Lambda @Michael-sqlbot