# AWS new line in JSON body of an API Gateway -> SNS request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

There is an API-Gateway - SNS integration.
Request body is application/json

Integration parameters:

- Subject: method.request.body.Subject
- Message: method.request.body.Message
- TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:*******:some-topic'
- HTTP Headers: Content-Type='application/json'
- Content handling : passthrough

Request body example:

```
{
  "Subject": "Hello World", 
  "Message": "qwerty"
}
```

Now I'm struggling to make it pass new line characters (\n, \r\n, "\r\n" and many others combinations) inside the message to SNS. Value of 'Message' key is getting passed "as is".

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I answered a question here that might help you with this... the other question was about SQS, but my answer was actually adapted from my own solution, which was developed for use with SNS.  The query APIs for the two services are so similar that the necessary changes are minor.  It allows your entire request body to be passed as the payload to SNS... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566676/1695906

Comment: Doesn't seems to work with SNS

"Message":"When Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, URL cannot include query-string parameters (after '?'): '/?Action=Publish&TopicArn=...