# How to write to a write-only SQS queue without an access key and secret key

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a website that writes messages from the client side to an Amazon SQS Queue. Everybody is allowed to write to the queue. We have a server-side process that reads the queue messages and processes them.

The Queue is configured with write access to everybody, here is its policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:.../SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [{
      "Sid": "Sid1537097246229",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:..."
  }]
}
```

However, we can't seem to be able to write to the queue without an access key and secret key. The AWS SDK returns an error saying that credentials have not been provided. We're using the code as described in the [AWS SQS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend allowing unauthenticated access to an SQS queue, but if you have to do this then you should be able to make unauthenticated requests through the JavaScript SDK as follows:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });

const params = {
  DelaySeconds: 10,
  MessageAttributes: {
    Title: {
      DataType: 'String',
      StringValue: 'The Whistler',
    },
    Author: {
      DataType: 'String',
      StringValue: 'John Grisham',
    },
  },
  MessageBody: 'NY Times fiction bestseller 12/11/2016.',
  QueueUrl: 'QUEUE_URL_HERE',
};

sqs.makeUnauthenticatedRequest('sendMessage', params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Success', data.MessageId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually don't see why unauthenticated requests are a problem here. The queue is writable by everyone, in a system that doesn't even have user registration. Whatever other mechanism I use, will essentially allow everybody to write a message to the queue.

Comment: The risk is probably not high but an open SQS queue is obviously open to abuse by anyone who discovers the URL. That could cause problems for your app (reading unexpected message content) and cost you money (SQS is not a free service).

Comment: Indeed, but the exact same risk exists if I restrict access to the queue, and let everybody download javascript code that writes to the queue.

Comment: Right, hard-coded credentials client-side are equally problematic. Ideally, all clients would authenticate (e.g. via Cognito) but I understand that in certain situations this may seem onerous. Anyhow, I just wanted to highlight the potential risks so that readers are fully-informed.

Answer (score 3):

Your default policy with `"Principal": "*"` still requires that the sender provide some AWS principal. As stated in the Prerequisites of the document you provided:

> Create a shared configurations file with your user credentials. For more information about providing a shared credentials file, see Loading Credentials in Node.js from the Shared Credentials File.

Have you considered using API Gateway as a proxy to your SQS queue? One example of doing so is defined at https://dzone.com/articles/creating-aws-service-proxy-for-amazon-sqs . I would recommend setting up a proxy to the SQS and having a POST endpoint such as

```
POST::/myQueueName/messages
```

That will change how your users interact with the queue, but it allows you to lock down the queue to only a service user for reading and writing, which follows the least-privilege policy. Then your API Gateway endpoint can be protected with an API key, left wide-open to the internet, or even protected with IAM roles, based on your preferences.

Comment: Good suggestion, API Gateway... feels much better than anonymous queue access.  Another (lightweight) example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566676/1695906

Comment: Why? Why is anonymous access to the API gateway better than anonymous access directly to SQS? In both cases everybody can write to the queue, and in both cases if I decide to shut down the public access, I just need to change the permissions, either on the gateway or the queue.

Comment: With the scenario you describe, SQS is basically a backend db for your application. In the traditional view, it just feels safer to have these things shielded from direct interaction with the users you know and those you don't know. Anonymous or not, APIG allows you to define throttling limits per IP if someone tries making too many requests, unlike SQS. And having the gateway there gives you the flexibility to switch out to different queues in the backend or replace it with a lambda function if you ever need to do more processing on the ingress side, before storing to the queue.

Comment: Throttling and limits per IP! That's a good reason to use it! The flexibility of switching queues or even replacing the queue with something else is not required in this particular case.