# How to use API Gateway and Mapping Templates with SQS Integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I had an API Gateway endpoint setup that, through a Mapping Template, takes the body of the request and some requester meta, combines them, and sends that payload to a stream. Here is what it looked like-

```
RequestTemplates:
    application/json: >
      #set($dataRecord = "{
          ""body"" : $input.json('$'),
          ""context"" : {
              ""client_ip"" : ""$context.identity.sourceIp"",
              ""user_agent"" : ""$context.identity.userAgent""
          }
      }")
      {
        "DeliveryStreamName": "event-firehose",
        "Record": { "Data": "$util.base64Encode($dataRecord)" }
      }
```

Now, i'd like to replace the stream with an sqs queue. The problem I'm having is that the Mapping Template is no longer respected. I have to specify the body of the message through the `MessageBody` query param in the integration, and can pass in `method.request.body` here, but I can't figure out how to either A) pass the transformed request via the mapping template, or B) construct the MessageBody query param so that it would contain both the request body and context.

How are Mapping Templates used when using SQS in the integration method?

Edit-

Michael and Kannaiyan in the comments both provided working answers

Comment: There may be more than one way to do it, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566676/1695906

Comment: Here is another complete example of the implementation, https://dzone.com/articles/creating-aws-service-proxy-for-amazon-sqs

Comment: Ah very interesting. Will give this a shot when I'm back in the office tomorrow