# Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized when using API Gateway to POST to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

Following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560626/is-it-possible-to-post-to-the-sqs-url-using-the-post-body/49566676#49566676), I tried to configure an API Gateway to send messages to SQS using POST instead of GET (I was able to make GET work).  When using POST, I get this response:

```
<AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

This is how my mapping template is configured

```
#set($clientKey = $input.params('clientkey'))
#set($url = "https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXX/SomeQueuePrefix-${clientKey}-SomeQueueEnvironment.fifo")
Action=SendMessage##
&QueueUrl=$util.urlEncode($url)##
&MessageGroupId=$input.params('messageGroupId')##
&MessageDeduplicationId=1##
&MessageBody=$util.urlEncode($input.body)
```

It looks like it maps the body correctly

```
Wed Nov 14 20:39:44 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request body after transformations: Action=SendMessage&QueueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fsqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com%2FXXXXXXXXX%2FSomeQueuePrefix-TEST-SomeQueueEnvironment.fifo&MessageGroupId=3&MessageDeduplicationId=1&MessageBody=%7B%0A++++%22configurationId%22%3A+1%0A%7D
Wed Nov 14 20:39:44 UTC 2018 : Sending request to https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com//
```

[Screenshot of my Integration Request setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoRix.png)

My IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX:CADAUTO-*-DEV.fifo"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:DeleteMessage"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anybody see why this isn't working?

Comment: Verify that in the *Integration Request*, the HTTP Method is set to `POST`.

Comment: Thanks.  I posted a screenshot of my Integration Request.  HTTP method is set to POST; does everything else look okay?

Comment: I don't think defining the path parameter in the integration request is doing what you intend, and that might be problematic, though I could be mistaken.  It is also possible that the service is getting confused by the lack of `##` at the end of the first two lines of your template.  I feel like whatever is causing this is going to be something relatively minor-seeming/subtle/non-obvious.

Comment: The path parameter is getting substituted correctly, as I can see the request is sent with the expected body (clientKey is 'TEST' in this example, and you can see that in the value of the QueueUrl parameter in the request body.  I wondered about the double slash in the request url, but if I take / out of the path override, the request fails.  I noticed that my region in the body is us-east-2 and our queue is in us-east-1.  I thought I had found the forehead-slappingly obvious reason for the error.  But after I changed it to us-east-1 I still get the same issue.

Comment: I added my policy in case there is anything in there.  I tried hardcoding 'TEST' as well as using '*" for resources, but neither had any effect.

Answer (score 11):

SQS expects content type to be 'Content-Type' to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. setting this in HTTP headers in API gateway settings solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have just experienced the same issue. Using @Hari Krishnan's suggestion above was part of the solution; and I needed to use an additional mapping template for my use case.
[Step 6 of the following tutorial](https://medium.com/@pranaysankpal/aws-api-gateway-proxy-for-sqs-simple-queue-service-5b08fe18ce50)   solved my problems for me.