# More interesting and useful API Gateway integration into AWS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

There is instructions on how to integrate between API Gateway and SNS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html) but this is a bit of a toy example.

I want to know how I can subscribe to a topic via API Gateway -> SNS Integration.

And to this purpose what I'm looking is general documentation on doing this as I assume it is possible. If you can ListTopics (which the example indicates) surely you can do other things...

Edit: So I now know that when I do an integration into SNS it sends the following to SNS: https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=CreateTopic

So that's a good start as that is how to call SNS to create a topic.

So now the question is how to I parameterise this?

I have also figured out that I can do from post to the SNS endpoint and thus include my parameters. However, the I get a signature not present error...

Comment: Do you mean... like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566676/1695906

Comment: Yes, I found that one but I get a 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details'. error when I follow it.

Comment: That sounds like maybe one or more of the Integration Request settings isn't consistent with my example, or perhaps you're mixing query string and body parameters in a way API Gateway doesn't understand.  That definitely works, though.  I use that exact setup with SNS or SQS (depending on the use case) to catch webhooks.

Comment: maybe it's a call that requires authentication?

Comment: That's what "execution role" is for.  But also, the signature error is *never* a permissions problem.  When a signature does not match, it's being calculated incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was key. Turned that I needed to send a POST and Not a Get as I was doing. I assume that because I was using get there was some anomaly with the mechanism it was using to generate the signature

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185603/discussion-between-michael-wiles-and-michael-sqlbot).