# Unable to send large payload to SNS topic from API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

I've implemented an API gateway endpoint that sends messages to the SNS topic when new requests are coming. In common, it works perfectly except the cases when I am trying to send a large payload to the SNS topic. In this case, I've got a bad request from SNS API even If I do not exceed the SNS or API Gateway limits and quotas. 
For example, I am getting this message if I will send the next payload which will consist of 15k letters 'a' or if the array will contain about 8k integers:

> {
>       "count": 1,
>       "data": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa... .",
>       "flag": 1,
>       "arr": [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-requestParameters.html)
>   }

As I understand the reason for such behavior is hidden in the next line of code in my CloudFormation template:

```
integration.request.querystring.Message: "method.request.body"
integration.request.querystring.TopicArn: !Sub "'${some-topic-arn}'"
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-requestParameters.html) we could use **body** type instead of **querystring**  but it is didn't works. 
Also, I have tried to use request template mapping and send **topicArn** via querystring and the message via template mapping. But it is also doesn't works.

So can anyone told me what I am doing wrong and how to solve the issue with getting bad request error when sending large payload via HTTP POST request?

Here is my current CloudFormation template: 
    /v1/someApiEndpoint:
            post:
              requestBody:
                content:
                  application/json:
                    schema:
                      $ref: "#/components/schemas/SomeApiModel"
                required: true
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: "200 response"
                ....

```
            '500':
              description: "500 response"
              content:
                application/json:
                  schema:
                    $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorMessage"

          x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: "SomeApiModelValidator"
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            type: "aws"
            httpMethod: "POST"
            uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sns:action/Publish"
            credentials: !GetAtt SomeApiRole.Arn
            responses:
              '2\d{2}':
                statusCode: 200
            requestParameters:
              integration.request.header.Content-Type: "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
              integration.request.querystring.Message: "method.request.body"
              integration.request.querystring.TopicArn: !Sub "'${SomeTopicArn}'"
            passthroughBehavior: "NEVER"
            requestTemplates:
              application/json: |
               #set($input.path('$').payload = { "userIdentity": $util.parseJson($context.authorizer.userIdentity), "data": $util.parseJson($input.body) })
               #set($encodedJson = $util.urlEncode($input.json('$.payload')))
```

Here is my model definition which I sends to API gateway and then transfer to SNS topic:

```
class SomeApiModel
{
  int count; 
  string data; 
  int flag;
  int[] arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

After many hours spent on the investigation, I finally found the problem and fixed it. 
As was mentioned by [Michael-sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) in the next [post about API GW and SQS integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566676/1179843) we need to override the path to SNS publish endpoint. 
Btw, thanks you saved my life =)

In case if someone will also stumble this issue here is a solution:

1. First of all. Replace the **URI** property inside **x-amazon-apigateway-integration:** section from this:

> uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sns:action/Publish"`

to this:

> uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sns:path//"

It will override the path as

2. Remove next two lines of code from integration request parameter section:

> ```
> integration.request.querystring.Message: "method.request.body"
> integration.request.querystring.TopicArn: !Sub "'${SomeTopicArn}'"
> ```

3. Put TopicArn, Message and Action parameters inside body request template:
   requestTemplates:

> ```
> application/json:
>     !Sub Action=Publish&TopicArn=$util.urlEncode('${my-topic-arn}')&Message=$util.urlEncode($input.body)##
> ```

Here is complete CloudFormation template definition for this integration:

```
             x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: "aws"
                httpMethod: "POST"
                uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sns:path//"
                credentials: !GetAtt my-personal-role.Arn
                responses:
                  '2\d{2}':
                    statusCode: 200
                requestParameters:
                  integration.request.header.Content-Type: "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
                passthroughBehavior: "NEVER"
                requestTemplates:
                  application/json:
                    !Sub Action=Publish&TopicArn=$util.urlEncode('${my-topic-arn}')&Message=$util.urlEncode($input.body)##
```

Pay attention to **Content-Type** property. It should be surrounded by single quotas `` as a single word.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. For requestTemplates how can I substitute The value of ${my-topic-arn} with the ARN of an SNS topic that is created within the same Clouformation YAML  @Tequila